# Difficulties with 'Remember me' function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So, I'm trying to create a 'remember me' function in the login process in my laravel application. I created a basic form with email, password and remember me checkbox as input, as can be seen below:

```
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-cs-offset-5" id="content">

    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'sessions.store']) }}

        <div>

            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}

            {{ Form::email('email') }}

        </div>

        <div>

            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}

            {{ Form::password('password') }}

        </div>

        <div>

            {{ Form::label('remember', 'Remember me:') }}
            {{ Form::checkbox('remember', 'Remember-me') }}

        </div>

        <div>{{ Form::submit('login') }}</div>

    {{ Form::close() }}

</div>
```

This posts to the function below. But what happens right now, is that the user is **always** logged in with the `true` parameter. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function store()
{

    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    $remember = Input::get('remember');

    if ($remember == 'Remember-me') {

        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
        {

            return Redirect::intended('/');

        }

        return Redirect::back()->withInput(); 

    } else {

        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
        {

            return Redirect::intended('/');

        }

        return Redirect::back()->withInput(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: How is it that you know that the user is remembered? Are you looking at the session, the cookies or somewhere else?

Comment: By testing it out manually. Logged in with checkbox checked, closed the browser and then reopened the page. Did the same without the checkbox checked and the behaviour is no different.

Comment: From reading the "similar questions" this is because of the session not the remember me. Closing the browser does not end your session (this is clear in all the other questions). Make sure you are actually logging out and check to make sure the session is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `true` as the third parameter of `Auth::attempt` will *remember* the login on success. Additionally your `$remember` check makes no sense because checkbox is supposed to represent a boolean value and `Input::get` returns it as either `1` or `null` which evaluates to `true` or `false` respectively.

What you probably want is this:

```php
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('email', 'password');
    $remember = Input::get('remember');

    if (Auth::attempt($input, $remember)
    {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput(); 
}
```

Comment: @User183849481 For how long?

Comment: Even after rebooting the computer ;p

Comment: Check the cookies expiration time. It's likely that your browser doesn't clear them on shut down and you come back after reboot before the normal login session has expired.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons remember me is hard to do right  (and there are many) is that the first time someone logs in with the box checked they need to login conventionally and that triggers the storage that you are going to do  which allows them to log in without supplying their user name and password  when they come back after their session has expired and they have closed their browser etc. So the initial authentication must be totally normal except for the addition of the step where the storage for future login  happens.  The remember me box being checked plays *no role* in that initial authentication.  Assuming you are going to store the data in a cookie, checking the box means that after successful authentication the cookie is created  and the other logic that will be needed for remember me authentication is implemented (and I won't go into the issues around that).

Later when they come back they shouldn't need to check the box or anything like that, they should just be logged in. That's when the remember me functionality comes into play however it is that you are implementing that.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I'm doing here. A user only needs to check that checkbox once for him to remain logged in for all eternity. But now it's also doing that when a user does not check the box, e.g. he wants to log in again next time.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the remember me  cookie is always created? You're sure it isn't that the regular session is still active?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
```

The View looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" />
        <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
    </div>
```

Off an old tutorial I don't know where I found, but it works.

Comment: `Input::has('remember')` is a boolean anyway. Why the 'if true, return true, otherwise return false' nonsense?

Comment: And what did you use for the value of the checkbox?